# Plataformas que executam Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Alguém sabe me informar quais plataformas (Windows, Linux, Mac, etc.) rodam o Tomcat 9.0?
Se possível, indiquem uma referência para tal informação.
Grato.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite amigo,as três plataformas suportam o tomcat em todas as versões.

Preparando o Tomcat em casa
Baixe o Tomcat 7 em http://tomcat.apache.org/ na página de downloads da versão que escolher, você precisa de uma "Binary Distribution". Mesmo no windows, dê preferência a versão .zip, para você entender melhor o processo de inicialização do servidor. A versão executável é apenas um wrapper para executar a JVM, já que o Tomcat é 100% Java.

O Tomcat foi por muito tempo considerado implementação padrão e referência das novas versões da API de servlets. Ele também é o servlet container padrão utilizado pelo JBoss. Ele continua em primeira posição no mercado, mas hoje tem esse lugar disputado pelo Jetty e pelo Grizzly (esse último é o servlet container que faz parte do servidor de aplicação da Oracle/Sun, o Glassfish).

Entre no diretório de instalação e execute o script startup.sh:

cd apache-tomcat/bin
./startup.sh
Entre no diretório de instalação do tomcat e rode o programa shutdown.sh:

cd apache-tomcat/bin
./shutdown.sh
Aprenderemos futuramente como iniciar o container de dentro do próprio Eclipse, por comodidade e para facilitar o uso do debug.

Tomcat no Windows

Para instalar o Tomcat no Windows basta executar o arquivo .exe que pode ser baixado no site do Tomcat (como falamos, dê preferência ao zip). Depois disso, você pode usar os scripts startup.bat e shutdown.bat, analogamente aos scripts do Linux.
Tô tomate vai funcionar em qualquer ambiente compatível com o Java Enterprise Edition, seja o Linux, Windows ou Mac OS.

Referência: https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/o-que-e-java-ee/#3-6-preparando-o-tomcat-em-casa
   CAP 3.6

Se tiver o Java instalado na máquina a ele vai rodar,
Link pára download do tomcat.